# Batch file for android that runs at startup

Tags: files, command-line, vanilla-android

On my windows laptop, I have a batch file which checks for a specific file and deletes it. My question is, is this possible on android, to make a file that runs at startup (without root), checks for the existence of a directory called "thumbnails" in /storage/sdcard0/DCIM", if exists, delete. Answers greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure that is possible. Many [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) apps (see our [automation tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/automation/info)) offer that. I e.g. use [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker) (see: [tasker tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info)) which offers to perform actions on device boot, and can execute shell commands. So a typical Tasker profile could be fired "on device boot" to "execute shell command" `rm -rf  /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/thumbnails`. No check needed for the existence of that directory: If it existes, that command would remove it – and if it not exists, result is the same :)

While Tasker is not free (there's a 7 day trial, though) there are other free [automation apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_automation) you could check with. I don't have a list of which ones provide on-boot command execution, so you had to look that up yourself.

In case your device is rooted, you'd have additional possibilities – e.g. utilizing [init scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init.d). If your device doesn't support them as-shipped, there are [some apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_sysmaint#group_1054) which could help adding that feature.

---

<sup>Disclosure: the linked app lists are my product, so those links go to my website.</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much, but is there a way that I could do that without third party apps?

Comment: Please read the last paragraph again: If your device is rooted and supports init scripts, you can. Otherwise I'm not aware of any such possibility.

Comment: Wow, I Just bought tasker, IT'S AMAZING!!! I would never have known there was such a thing! IT IS ALMIGHTY POWERFUL! thanks for recomending it.

Comment: It definitely is! I'm using it for years already. So if you're looking for ideas, see my [Tasker resource collection](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker) :)

Comment: Great page. Read through it in about half an hour! Was totally worth it!!